# How to you make the slider reflect changes made in the input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
<div id='slider'></div>
<div id='start'><input value="1"></div>
<div id='stop'><input value="99"></div>

 $.ui.slider.prototype._slide = function ( event, index, newVal ) {
              var otherVal,
                newValues,
                allowed;

              if ( this.options.values && this.options.values.length ) {
                otherVal = this.values( index ? 0 : 1 );
                if ( newVal !== this.values( index ) ) {
                  newValues = this.values();
                  newValues[ index ] = newVal;
                  // A slide can be canceled by returning false from the slide callback
                  allowed = this._trigger( "slide", event, {
                    handle: this.handles[ index ],
                    value: newVal,
                    values: newValues
                  } );
                  otherVal = this.values( index ? 0 : 1 );
                  if ( allowed !== false ) {
                    this.values( index, newVal, true );
                  }
                }
              } else {
                if ( newVal !== this.value() ) {
                  // A slide can be canceled by returning false from the slide callback
                  allowed = this._trigger( "slide", event, {
                    handle: this.handles[ index ],
                    value: newVal
                  } );
                  if ( allowed !== false ) {
                    this.value( newVal );
                  }
                }
              }
            }

$('#slider').slider({
    min: '0',
    max: '99',
    range: true,
    values: [0,99],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1]) {
                                          if(ui.handle == $("#slider a")[0]) {
                                            $("#slider").slider("values", 1, ui.value+1);
                                            ui.values[0] = ui.value;
                                            ui.values[1] = ui.value+1;
                                          } else {
                                            $("#slider").slider("values", 0, ui.value-1);
                                            ui.values[0] = ui.value-1;
                                            ui.values[1] = ui.value;
                                          }
                                        }

        var minutes0 = Math.floor(ui.values[0]);


        var minutes1 = Math.floor(ui.values[1]);


        $('#start input').val(minutes0);
        $('#stop input').val(minutes1);
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nk8ap/18/

Right now, when i drag the handlers, the change is reflected on the text box.

But how can I make it so that when I manually type in the numbers, that change is reflected on the handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add an event handler for the inputs, and change the slider values :

```
$('#start input, #stop input').on('change', function() {
    var val = [$('#start input').val(), $('#stop input').val()];
    $("#slider").slider('values', val);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nk8ap/25/)

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thank you, but is that way to make the value change once it is typed in? Because right now, you need to hit enter or use your mouse to click outside of the text box in order for you to see the change? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, just use one of the key events instead, like keyup, here's a [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/Nk8ap/26/).......